# Extracting part of an src using split jquery

Tags: php, jquery

I;m trying to exract part of an src with jquery:

```
<iframe width="615" height="375" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4PzoS6ZgDsw?HD=1;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I want to extract the youtube id `'4PzoS6ZgDsw':`

This is how far I've got:

```
$youtubeVid = <iframe width="615" height="375" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/4PzoS6ZgDsw?HD=1;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

var youtubeVid = '<?php echo $youtubeVid; ?>';
var urlsplit = youtubeVid.split("/");
var youtubeID = urlsplit[4];
```

This returns: `4PzoS6ZgDsw?HD=1;rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen><`

Any help muchly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var urlsplit = youtubeVid.split("?")[0];
var youtubeID = urlsplit.split('/')[4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var urlsplit = youtubeVid.split("/");
var youtubeID = urlsplit[4];
var tmp = urlsplit[4].split("?");
```

-> tmp[0]..